# Hourly Backup Firestore Databse

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, backup

I need to back up my prod server Firestore DB hourly. I know about `exportDocuments` but it incurs one read operation per document exported. I have more than 3 million and these are increasing day by day.

Is it possible to export docs that are added/updated in a given period like the last 1 hour?

I already have Cloud Scheduler + Cloud Pub/Sub + function-based backup system. It is backing up all the docs. It is costing too much.

Comment: I contributed to that project. Does that project help you? https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-firestore-backup

Answer (score 0):

If you need to schedule some operations in Firestore, you can consider using [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/), which allows you to schedule HTTP requests or Cloud Pub/Sub messages to [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions) that you deploy.

If you need to get the documents that are added/updated in a given period of time, like the last 1 hour, then don't forget to add a timestamp field to your documents. In this way, you can query based on that timestamp field.

Comment: I already have Cloud Scheduler +  Cloud Pub/Sub backup system. 
But as I have already told we have more than 3 million and it is backing up all the docs.
It is costing too much.

I want to reduce this cost and sorry we don't have an updated timestamp field at present.
Can we get an update_at detail from some metadata of firestore doc?

Comment: You can get some data from a [SnapshotMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata) oject but there are no details about the last update. You have to add that, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Hey Ankur. Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Answer (score 0):

To get docs that are added/updated in a given period like in the last 1 hour, add a field to the document, say `lastUpdated`, and keep its value current with every insert/update.

Then query for incremental documents like, `where("lastUpdated", ">", "lastExportTimestamp")` from the backup function, `lastExportTimestamp` being the time of last export (and may be stored in a separate collection).

See an example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example#read-chats).

Hope this clarifies, else leave a comment.

**P.S.** Please be advised that this approach may still need a full periodic backup (say daily), for ease of restore process, if/when required.